# Sorting Algorithm advise if-else

Tags: java, android, arrays, algorithm, if-statement

I need a bit of guidance on how to sort the values inside of my array.

So, I have 2 `Arrays` for X and Z accelerometer readings.
I want to sort them out into 4 categories Excellent, Good, Average, and Poor.
Each of this categories have their own array.

After all the values of X and Z `arrays` are sorted and the values of 1 and 0 are inserted into each of the Excellent, Good, Average, and Poor arrays, I want to pass the grade of the highest value from the 4 categories(adding the data inside each category array).

The problem is that the `if-else statement` doesn't go the next `else if`, even though the reading is  less than 1 and and more than -1.
So by then end, I always get the 'Excellent' grade even though I shook my phone like crazy.

Here are the range:

- Excellent: More than -1 and less than 1
- Good: Less than -2 and more than 2
- Average: less than -4 and more than 4
- Poor: less than -6 and more than 6

---

```
for(int i = 0; i < ArrayX.size(); i++){
    //  sumX = (sumX + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ArrayX.get(i))));
    //  sumY = (sumY + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ArrayY.get(i))));
    X = String.valueOf(ArrayX.get(i));
    Y = String.valueOf(ArrayY.get(i));
    Z = String.valueOf(ArrayZ.get(i));
    float valX = Float.parseFloat(X);
    float valZ = Float.parseFloat(Z);


    if(valX<excellentRate||valX>(-excellentRate))
    {
        ArrayPoor.add(0);
        ArrayAverage.add(0);
        ArrayGood.add(0);
        ArrayExcellent.add(1);
    }
    else if(valX<=goodRate||valX>=(-goodRate)){
        ArrayPoor.add(0);
        ArrayAverage.add(0);
        ArrayGood.add(1);
        ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    }
    else if(valX<=averageRate||valX>=(-averageRate)){
        ArrayPoor.add(0);
        ArrayAverage.add(1);
        ArrayGood.add(0);
        ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    }
    else if(valX<poorRate||valX>(-poorRate)){
        ArrayPoor.add(1);
        ArrayAverage.add(0);
        ArrayGood.add(0);
        ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    }


    if(valZ<(0.00f)||valZ>0.00f)
    {
        ArrayPoor.add(0);
        ArrayAverage.add(0);
        ArrayGood.add(0);
        ArrayExcellent.add(1);
    }
    else if(valZ<=(-2.00f)||valZ>=2.00f){
        ArrayPoor.add(0);
        ArrayAverage.add(0);
        ArrayGood.add(1);
        ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    }
    else if(valZ<=(-4.00f)||valZ>=4.00f){
        ArrayPoor.add(0);
        ArrayAverage.add(1);
        ArrayGood.add(0);
        ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    }
    else if(valZ<(-6.00f)||valZ>4.00f){
        ArrayPoor.add(1);
        ArrayAverage.add(0);
        ArrayGood.add(0);
        ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    }



    //codes for sending testSet Details             
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+ " TS= " +TS_ID + " TSA= "+ TSA_ID  + X + " " + Y + " " + Z);
    String jsonOutput = "http://172.20.34.112/IBBTS_WebService_MobileAndDevice/Service1.asmx/setAccReadings";               

    if (isOnline()) {
        requestAccelData(jsonOutput);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(ResultSend.this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


for (int j=0; j<ArrayExcellent.size(); j++){
    sumPoor = sumPoor +Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ArrayPoor.get(j)));
    sumAverage = sumAverage + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ArrayAverage.get(j)));
    sumGood = sumGood + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ArrayGood.get(j)));
    sumExcellent = sumExcellent + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ArrayExcellent.get(j)));
}

if(sumExcellent>=sumGood && sumExcellent>=sumAverage && sumExcellent>=sumPoor )
    grade ="Excellent";
else if(sumGood>=sumExcellent && sumGood>=sumAverage && sumGood>=sumPoor){
    grade ="Good";
}
else if(sumAverage>=sumExcellent && sumAverage>=sumGood && sumAverage>=sumPoor){
    grade ="Average";
}
else if(sumPoor>=sumExcellent && sumPoor>=sumGood && sumPoor>=sumAverage){
    grade ="Poor";
}

Intent intSummary = new Intent(ResultSend.this, ResultSummary.class);
intSummary.putExtra("gradePassed", grade);
intSummary.putExtra("TestName", TestName);
startActivity(intSummary);
}
```

I also had tried with other methods like this:

```
checker = compare(valX, excellentRateX);
if(checker == 1){
    ArrayPoor.add(0);
    ArrayAverage.add(0);
    ArrayGood.add(0);
    ArrayExcellent.add(1);
    checker = 0;
    checker = compare(valX, goodRateX);
}
else if(checker == -1){
    checker = compare(valX, goodRateX);
}
else if(checker == 1){
    ArrayPoor.add(0);
    ArrayAverage.add(0);
    ArrayGood.add(1);
    ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    checker = 0;
    checker = compare(valX, averageRateX);
}
else if(checker == -1){
    checker = compare(valX, averageRateX);
}
else if(checker == 1){
    ArrayPoor.add(0);
    ArrayAverage.add(1);
    ArrayGood.add(0);
    ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    checker = 0;
    checker = compare(valX, poorRateX);
}
else if(checker == -1){
    checker = compare(valX, poorRateX);
}
else if(checker == 1){
    ArrayPoor.add(1);
    ArrayAverage.add(0);
    ArrayGood.add(0);
    ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    checker = 0;
}


checker = compare(valZ, excellentRateZ);
if(checker == 1){
    ArrayPoor.add(0);
    ArrayAverage.add(0);
    ArrayGood.add(0);
    ArrayExcellent.add(1);
    checker = 0;
    checker = compare(valZ, goodRateZ);
}
else if(checker == -1){
    checker = compare(valZ, goodRateX);
}
else if(checker == 1){
    ArrayPoor.add(0);
    ArrayAverage.add(0);
    ArrayGood.add(1);
    ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    checker = 0;
    checker = compare(valZ, averageRateZ);
}
else if(checker == -1){
    checker = compare(valZ, averageRateZ);
}
else if(checker == 1){
    ArrayPoor.add(0);
    ArrayAverage.add(1);
    ArrayGood.add(0);
    ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    checker = 0;
    checker = compare(valZ, poorRateZ);
}
else if(checker == -1){
    checker = compare(valZ, poorRateZ);
}
else if(checker == 1){
    ArrayPoor.add(1);
    ArrayAverage.add(0);
    ArrayGood.add(0);
    ArrayExcellent.add(0);
    checker = 0;
} 

public static int compare(float f1, float f2) {
   if (f1 < f2 && f1 > -f2){
        return 1;
        } // value is within the specifications
   else{
        return -1;
        } // value is outside the specifications
}
```

Edited the code based on the suggestion below and now it's working!

```
            if(valX <excellentRateX && valX >(-excellentRateX))
            {
                ArrayPoor.add(0);
                ArrayAverage.add(0);
                ArrayGood.add(0);
                ArrayExcellent.add(1);
            }
            else if(valX <= goodRateX && valX >= (-goodRateX)){
                ArrayPoor.add(0);
                ArrayAverage.add(0);
                ArrayGood.add(1);
                ArrayExcellent.add(0);
            }
            else if(valX <= averageRateX && valX>=(-averageRateX)){
                ArrayPoor.add(0);
                ArrayAverage.add(1);
                ArrayGood.add(0);
                ArrayExcellent.add(0);
            }
            else if(valX <= poorRateX && valX >= (-poorRateX)){
                ArrayPoor.add(1);
                ArrayAverage.add(0);
                ArrayGood.add(0);
                ArrayExcellent.add(0);
            }
            else {
                ArrayPoor.add(1);
                ArrayAverage.add(0);
                ArrayGood.add(0);
                ArrayExcellent.add(0);
            }


            if(valZ<excellentRateZ  && valZ>-excellentRateZ)
            {
                ArrayPoor.add(0);
                ArrayAverage.add(0);
                ArrayGood.add(0);
                ArrayExcellent.add(1);
            }
            else if(valZ <= goodRateZ && valZ >= (-goodRateZ)){
                ArrayPoor.add(0);
                ArrayAverage.add(0);
                ArrayGood.add(1);
                ArrayExcellent.add(0);
            }
            else if(valZ <= averageRateZ && valZ>=(-averageRateZ)){
                ArrayPoor.add(0);
                ArrayAverage.add(1);
                ArrayGood.add(0);
                ArrayExcellent.add(0);
            }
            else if(valZ < poorRateZ && valZ>(-poorRateZ)){
                ArrayPoor.add(1);
                ArrayAverage.add(0);
                ArrayGood.add(0);
                ArrayExcellent.add(0);
            } 
            else {
                ArrayPoor.add(1);
                ArrayAverage.add(0);
                ArrayGood.add(0);
                ArrayExcellent.add(0);
            }
```

Comment: `Poor: less than -6 and more than 6` your code says different, it´s less then `-6` but will ignore the second condition `valZ>4.00f` since it´s covered by the previous one yet. In addition everything will get caught by your first if condition. `(valZ<(0.00f)||valZ>0.00f)` since this condition also includes the following ones.

Comment: I dont understand...What if the value is 1.5?

Comment: Also...your conditions of good, average and poor will never be met. How can a number be less than -2 `and` greater than 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first code snippet I can see the following if condition :

```
 if(valX<excellentRate||valX>(-excellentRate))
```

If the `excellentRate = 1` then it will be interpreted as

> if valX is less than 1 or valX more than -1

Since every real number is "either less than 1 or more than -1", therefore this condition will always be true.

You should rather use :

```
if(valX<excellentRate && valX>(-excellentRate))
```

And do same for other if statements.

P.S. : I have low reputation so couldn't point this out in comment, therefore I am writing an answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the enlightenment! It's now finally working! Will update the code on top.

Comment: If its working for you then accept this answer, so that others will know that your question is answered.